# jupyter notebook showing csv file output broken in lines

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, horizontal-scrolling

I am new to Jupyter notebook. I came across it to execute great expectation test cases.
I dowonloaded jupyter lab(3.4.4) and installed in my mac just before sometime.
I am trying to execute python code of great expectations on a sample csv file i got from internet. I checked the file manually it is in a good shape.

```
import great_expectations as ge

my_df = ge.read_csv("/Users/someuser/Desktop//100SalesRecords.csv")

print(my_df)
```

when i am trying to print it is showing me the result in lines wraped as below

```
                                   Region                           Country  \
0               Australia and Oceania                            Tuvalu   
1   Central America and the Caribbean                           Grenada   
2                              Europe                            Russia   
3                  Sub-Saharan Africa             Sao Tome and Principe   
4                  Sub-Saharan Africa                            Rwanda   
5               Australia and Oceania                   Solomon Islands   
6                  Sub-Saharan Africa                            Angola   
7                  Sub-Saharan Africa                      Burkina Faso   
8                  Sub-Saharan Africa             Republic of the Congo   
9                  Sub-Saharan Africa                           Senegal   
10                               Asia                        Kyrgyzstan   
11                 Sub-Saharan Africa                        Cape Verde   
12                               Asia                        Bangladesh   
13  Central America and the Caribbean                          Honduras   
14                               Asia                          Mongolia   
15                             Europe                          Bulgaria   
16                               Asia                         Sri Lanka   
17                 Sub-Saharan Africa                          Cameroon   
18                               Asia                      Turkmenistan   
19              Australia and Oceania                        East Timor   
20                             Europe                            Norway   
21                             Europe                          Portugal   
22  Central America and the Caribbean                          Honduras   
23              Australia and Oceania                       New Zealand   
24                             Europe                          Moldova    
25                             Europe                            France   
26              Australia and Oceania                          Kiribati   
27                 Sub-Saharan Africa                              Mali   
28                             Europe                            Norway   
29                 Sub-Saharan Africa                        The Gambia   
30                             Europe                       Switzerland   
31                 Sub-Saharan Africa                       South Sudan   
32              Australia and Oceania                         Australia   
33                               Asia                           Myanmar   
34                 Sub-Saharan Africa                          Djibouti   
35  Central America and the Caribbean                        Costa Rica   
36       Middle East and North Africa                             Syria   
37                 Sub-Saharan Africa                        The Gambia   
38                               Asia                            Brunei   
39                             Europe                          Bulgaria   
40                 Sub-Saharan Africa                             Niger   
41       Middle East and North Africa                        Azerbaijan   
42                 Sub-Saharan Africa                        The Gambia   
43                             Europe                          Slovakia   
44                               Asia                           Myanmar   
45                 Sub-Saharan Africa                           Comoros   
46                             Europe                           Iceland   
47                             Europe                       Switzerland   
48                             Europe                         Macedonia   
49                 Sub-Saharan Africa                        Mauritania   
50                             Europe                           Albania   
51                 Sub-Saharan Africa                           Lesotho   
52       Middle East and North Africa                      Saudi Arabia   
53                 Sub-Saharan Africa                      Sierra Leone   
54                 Sub-Saharan Africa             Sao Tome and Principe   
55                 Sub-Saharan Africa                     Cote d'Ivoire   
56              Australia and Oceania                              Fiji   
57                             Europe                           Austria   
58                             Europe                    United Kingdom   
59                 Sub-Saharan Africa                          Djibouti   
60              Australia and Oceania                         Australia   
61                             Europe                        San Marino   
62                 Sub-Saharan Africa                          Cameroon   
63       Middle East and North Africa                             Libya   
64  Central America and the Caribbean                             Haiti   
65                 Sub-Saharan Africa                            Rwanda   
66                 Sub-Saharan Africa                             Gabon   
67  Central America and the Caribbean                            Belize   
68                             Europe                         Lithuania   
69                 Sub-Saharan Africa                        Madagascar   
70                               Asia                      Turkmenistan   
71       Middle East and North Africa                             Libya   
72                 Sub-Saharan Africa  Democratic Republic of the Congo   
73                 Sub-Saharan Africa                          Djibouti   
74       Middle East and North Africa                          Pakistan   
75                      North America                            Mexico   
76              Australia and Oceania    Federated States of Micronesia   
77                               Asia                              Laos   
78                             Europe                            Monaco   
79              Australia and Oceania                            Samoa    
80                             Europe                             Spain   
81       Middle East and North Africa                           Lebanon   
82       Middle East and North Africa                              Iran   
83                 Sub-Saharan Africa                            Zambia   
84                 Sub-Saharan Africa                             Kenya   
85                      North America                            Mexico   
86                 Sub-Saharan Africa             Sao Tome and Principe   
87                 Sub-Saharan Africa                        The Gambia   
88       Middle East and North Africa                            Kuwait   
89                             Europe                          Slovenia   
90                 Sub-Saharan Africa                      Sierra Leone   
91              Australia and Oceania                         Australia   
92       Middle East and North Africa                        Azerbaijan   
93                             Europe                           Romania   
94  Central America and the Caribbean                         Nicaragua   
95                 Sub-Saharan Africa                              Mali   
96                               Asia                          Malaysia   
97                 Sub-Saharan Africa                      Sierra Leone   
98                      North America                            Mexico   
99                 Sub-Saharan Africa                        Mozambique   

           ItemType SalesChannel OrderPriority   OrderDate    OrderID  \
0         Baby Food      Offline             H   5/28/2010  669165933   
1            Cereal       Online             C   8/22/2012  963881480   
2   Office Supplies      Offline             L    5/2/2014  341417157   
3            Fruits       Online             C   6/20/2014  514321792   
4   Office Supplies      Offline             L    2/1/2013  115456712   
5         Baby Food       Online             C    2/4/2015  547995746   
6         Household      Offline             M   4/23/2011  135425221   
7        Vegetables       Online             H   7/17/2012  871543967   
8     Personal Care      Offline             M   7/14/2015  770463311   
9            Cereal       Online             H   4/18/2014  616607081   
10       Vegetables       Online             H   6/24/2011  814711606   
11          Clothes      Offline             H    8/2/2014  939825713   
12          Clothes       Online             L   1/13/2017  187310731   
13        Household      Offline             H    2/8/2017  522840487   
14    Personal Care      Offline             C   2/19/2014  832401311   
15          Clothes       Online             M   4/23/2012  972292029   
16        Cosmetics      Offline             M  11/19/2016  419123971   
17        Beverages      Offline             C    4/1/2015  519820964   
18        Household      Offline             L  12/30/2010  441619336   
19             Meat       Online             L   7/31/2012  322067916   
20        Baby Food       Online             L   5/14/2014  819028031   
21        Baby Food       Online             H   7/31/2015  860673511   
22           Snacks       Online             L   6/30/2016  795490682   
23           Fruits       Online             H    9/8/2014  142278373   
24    Personal Care       Online             L    5/7/2016  740147912   
25        Cosmetics       Online             H   5/22/2017  898523128   
26           Fruits       Online             M  10/13/2014  347140347   
27           Fruits       Online             L    5/7/2010  686048400   
28        Beverages      Offline             C   7/18/2014  435608613   
29        Household      Offline             L   5/26/2012  886494815   
30        Cosmetics      Offline             M   9/17/2012  249693334   
31    Personal Care      Offline             C  12/29/2013  406502997   
32  Office Supplies       Online             C  10/27/2015  158535134   
33        Household      Offline             H   1/16/2015  177713572   
34           Snacks       Online             M   2/25/2017  756274640   
35    Personal Care      Offline             L    5/8/2017  456767165   
36           Fruits       Online             L  11/22/2011  162052476   
37             Meat       Online             M   1/14/2017  825304400   
38  Office Supplies       Online             L    4/1/2012  320009267   
39  Office Supplies       Online             M   2/16/2012  189965903   
40    Personal Care       Online             H   3/11/2017  699285638   
41        Cosmetics       Online             M    2/6/2010  382392299   
42           Cereal      Offline             H    6/7/2012  994022214   
43       Vegetables       Online             H   10/6/2012  759224212   
44          Clothes       Online             H  11/14/2015  223359620   
45           Cereal      Offline             H   3/29/2016  902102267   
46        Cosmetics       Online             C  12/31/2016  331438481   
47    Personal Care       Online             M  12/23/2010  617667090   
48          Clothes      Offline             C  10/14/2014  787399423   
49  Office Supplies      Offline             C   1/11/2012  837559306   
50          Clothes       Online             C    2/2/2010  385383069   
51           Fruits       Online             L   8/18/2013  918419539   
52           Cereal       Online             M   3/25/2013  844530045   
53  Office Supplies      Offline             M  11/26/2011  441888415   
54           Fruits      Offline             H   9/17/2013  508980977   
55          Clothes       Online             C    6/8/2012  114606559   
56          Clothes      Offline             C   6/30/2010  647876489   
57        Cosmetics      Offline             H   2/23/2015  868214595   
58        Household       Online             L    1/5/2012  955357205   
59        Cosmetics      Offline             H    4/7/2014  259353148   
60           Cereal      Offline             H    6/9/2013  450563752   
61        Baby Food       Online             L   6/26/2013  569662845   
62  Office Supplies       Online             M   11/7/2011  177636754   
63          Clothes      Offline             H  10/30/2010  705784308   
64        Cosmetics      Offline             H  10/13/2013  505716836   
65        Cosmetics      Offline             H  10/11/2013  699358165   
66    Personal Care      Offline             L    7/8/2012  228944623   
67          Clothes      Offline             M   7/25/2016  807025039   
68  Office Supplies      Offline             H  10/24/2010  166460740   
69          Clothes      Offline             L   4/25/2015  610425555   
70  Office Supplies       Online             M   4/23/2013  462405812   
71           Fruits       Online             L   8/14/2015  816200339   
72        Beverages       Online             C   5/26/2011  585920464   
73           Cereal       Online             H   5/20/2017  555990016   
74        Cosmetics      Offline             L    7/5/2013  231145322   
75        Household      Offline             C   11/6/2014  986435210   
76        Beverages       Online             C  10/28/2014  217221009   
77       Vegetables      Offline             C   9/15/2011  789176547   
78        Baby Food      Offline             H   5/29/2012  688288152   
79        Cosmetics       Online             H   7/20/2013  670854651   
80        Household      Offline             L  10/21/2012  213487374   
81          Clothes       Online             L   9/18/2012  663110148   
82        Cosmetics       Online             H  11/15/2016  286959302   
83           Snacks       Online             L    1/4/2011  122583663   
84       Vegetables       Online             L   3/18/2012  827844560   
85    Personal Care      Offline             L   2/17/2012  430915820   
86        Beverages      Offline             C   1/16/2011  180283772   
87        Baby Food      Offline             M    2/3/2014  494747245   
88           Fruits       Online             M   4/30/2012  513417565   
89        Beverages      Offline             C  10/23/2016  345718562   
90  Office Supplies      Offline             H   12/6/2016  621386563   
91        Beverages      Offline             H    7/7/2014  240470397   
92  Office Supplies       Online             M   6/13/2012  423331391   
93        Cosmetics       Online             H  11/26/2010  660643374   
94        Beverages      Offline             C    2/8/2011  963392674   
95          Clothes       Online             M   7/26/2011  512878119   
96           Fruits      Offline             L  11/11/2011  810711038   
97       Vegetables      Offline             C    6/1/2016  728815257   
98    Personal Care      Offline             M   7/30/2015  559427106   
99        Household      Offline             L   2/10/2012  665095412   

      ShipDate  UnitsSold  UnitPrice  UnitCost  TotalRevenue   TotalCost  \
0    6/27/2010       9925     255.28    159.42    2533654.00  1582243.50   
1    9/15/2012       2804     205.70    117.11     576782.80   328376.44   
2     5/8/2014       1779     651.21    524.96    1158502.59   933903.84   
3     7/5/2014       8102       9.33      6.92      75591.66    56065.84   
4     2/6/2013       5062     651.21    524.96    3296425.02  2657347.52   
5    2/21/2015       2974     255.28    159.42     759202.72   474115.08   
6    4/27/2011       4187     668.27    502.54    2798046.49  2104134.98   
7    7/27/2012       8082     154.06     90.93    1245112.92   734896.26   
8    8/25/2015       6070      81.73     56.67     496101.10   343986.90   
9    5/30/2014       6593     205.70    117.11    1356180.10   772106.23   
10   7/12/2011        124     154.06     90.93      19103.44    11275.32   
11   8/19/2014       4168     109.28     35.84     455479.04   149381.12   
12    3/1/2017       8263     109.28     35.84     902980.64   296145.92   
13   2/13/2017       8974     668.27    502.54    5997054.98  4509793.96   
14   2/23/2014       4901      81.73     56.67     400558.73   277739.67   
15    6/3/2012       1673     109.28     35.84     182825.44    59960.32   
16  12/18/2016       6952     437.20    263.33    3039414.40  1830670.16   
17   4/18/2015       5430      47.45     31.79     257653.50   172619.70   
18   1/20/2011       3830     668.27    502.54    2559474.10  1924728.20   
19   9/11/2012       5908     421.89    364.69    2492526.12  2154588.52   
20   6/28/2014       7450     255.28    159.42    1901836.00  1187679.00   
21    9/3/2015       1273     255.28    159.42     324971.44   202941.66   
22   7/26/2016       2225     152.58     97.44     339490.50   216804.00   
23   10/4/2014       2187       9.33      6.92      20404.71    15134.04   
24   5/10/2016       5070      81.73     56.67     414371.10   287316.90   
25    6/5/2017       1815     437.20    263.33     793518.00   477943.95   
26  11/10/2014       5398       9.33      6.92      50363.34    37354.16   
27   5/10/2010       5822       9.33      6.92      54319.26    40288.24   
28   7/30/2014       5124      47.45     31.79     243133.80   162891.96   
29    6/9/2012       2370     668.27    502.54    1583799.90  1191019.80   
30  10/20/2012       8661     437.20    263.33    3786589.20  2280701.13   
31   1/28/2014       2125      81.73     56.67     173676.25   120423.75   
32  11/25/2015       2924     651.21    524.96    1904138.04  1534983.04   
33    3/1/2015       8250     668.27    502.54    5513227.50  4145955.00   
34   2/25/2017       7327     152.58     97.44    1117953.66   713942.88   
35   5/21/2017       6409      81.73     56.67     523807.57   363198.03   
36   12/3/2011       3784       9.33      6.92      35304.72    26185.28   
37   1/23/2017       4767     421.89    364.69    2011149.63  1738477.23   
38    5/8/2012       6708     651.21    524.96    4368316.68  3521431.68   
39   2/28/2012       3987     651.21    524.96    2596374.27  2093015.52   
40   3/28/2017       3015      81.73     56.67     246415.95   170860.05   
41   2/25/2010       7234     437.20    263.33    3162704.80  1904929.22   
42    6/8/2012       2117     205.70    117.11     435466.90   247921.87   
43  11/10/2012        171     154.06     90.93      26344.26    15549.03   
44  11/18/2015       5930     109.28     35.84     648030.40   212531.20   
45   4/29/2016        962     205.70    117.11     197883.40   112659.82   
46  12/31/2016       8867     437.20    263.33    3876652.40  2334947.11   
47   1/31/2011        273      81.73     56.67      22312.29    15470.91   
48  11/14/2014       7842     109.28     35.84     856973.76   281057.28   
49   1/13/2012       1266     651.21    524.96     824431.86   664599.36   
50   3/18/2010       2269     109.28     35.84     247956.32    81320.96   
51   9/18/2013       9606       9.33      6.92      89623.98    66473.52   
52   3/28/2013       4063     205.70    117.11     835759.10   475817.93   
53    1/7/2012       3457     651.21    524.96    2251232.97  1814786.72   
54  10/24/2013       7637       9.33      6.92      71253.21    52848.04   
55   6/27/2012       3482     109.28     35.84     380512.96   124794.88   
56    8/1/2010       9905     109.28     35.84    1082418.40   354995.20   
57    3/2/2015       2847     437.20    263.33    1244708.40   749700.51   
58   2/14/2012        282     668.27    502.54     188452.14   141716.28   
59   4/19/2014       7215     437.20    263.33    3154398.00  1899925.95   
60    7/2/2013        682     205.70    117.11     140287.40    79869.02   
61    7/1/2013       4750     255.28    159.42    1212580.00   757245.00   
62  11/15/2011       5518     651.21    524.96    3593376.78  2896729.28   
63  11/17/2010       6116     109.28     35.84     668356.48   219197.44   
64  11/16/2013       1705     437.20    263.33     745426.00   448977.65   
65  11/25/2013       4477     437.20    263.33    1957344.40  1178928.41   
66    7/9/2012       8656      81.73     56.67     707454.88   490535.52   
67    9/7/2016       5498     109.28     35.84     600821.44   197048.32   
68  11/17/2010       8287     651.21    524.96    5396577.27  4350343.52   
69   5/28/2015       7342     109.28     35.84     802333.76   263137.28   
70   5/20/2013       5010     651.21    524.96    3262562.10  2630049.60   
71   9/30/2015        673       9.33      6.92       6279.09     4657.16   
72   7/15/2011       5741      47.45     31.79     272410.45   182506.39   
73   6/17/2017       8656     205.70    117.11    1780539.20  1013704.16   
74   8/16/2013       9892     437.20    263.33    4324782.40  2604860.36   
75  12/12/2014       6954     668.27    502.54    4647149.58  3494663.16   
76  11/15/2014       9379      47.45     31.79     445033.55   298158.41   
77  10/23/2011       3732     154.06     90.93     574951.92   339350.76   
78    6/2/2012       8614     255.28    159.42    2198981.92  1373243.88   
79    8/7/2013       9654     437.20    263.33    4220728.80  2542187.82   
80  11/30/2012       4513     668.27    502.54    3015902.51  2267963.02   
81   10/8/2012       7884     109.28     35.84     861563.52   282562.56   
82   12/8/2016       6489     437.20    263.33    2836990.80  1708748.37   
83    1/5/2011       4085     152.58     97.44     623289.30   398042.40   
84    4/7/2012       6457     154.06     90.93     994765.42   587135.01   
85   3/20/2012       6422      81.73     56.67     524870.06   363934.74   
86   1/21/2011       8829      47.45     31.79     418936.05   280673.91   
87   3/20/2014       5559     255.28    159.42    1419101.52   886215.78   
88   5/18/2012        522       9.33      6.92       4870.26     3612.24   
89  11/25/2016       4660      47.45     31.79     221117.00   148141.40   
90  12/14/2016        948     651.21    524.96     617347.08   497662.08   
91   7/11/2014       9389      47.45     31.79     445508.05   298476.31   
92   7/24/2012       2021     651.21    524.96    1316095.41  1060944.16   
93  12/25/2010       7910     437.20    263.33    3458252.00  2082940.30   
94   3/21/2011       8156      47.45     31.79     387002.20   259279.24   
95    9/3/2011        888     109.28     35.84      97040.64    31825.92   
96  12/28/2011       6267       9.33      6.92      58471.11    43367.64   
97   6/29/2016       1485     154.06     90.93     228779.10   135031.05   
98    8/8/2015       5767      81.73     56.67     471336.91   326815.89   
99   2/15/2012       5367     668.27    502.54    3586605.09  2697132.18   

    TotalProfit  
0     951410.50  
1     248406.36  
2     224598.75  
3      19525.82  
4     639077.50  
5     285087.64  
6     693911.51  
7     510216.66  
8     152114.20  
9     584073.87  
10      7828.12  
11    306097.92  
12    606834.72  
13   1487261.02  
14    122819.06  
15    122865.12  
16   1208744.24  
17     85033.80  
18    634745.90  
19    337937.60  
20    714157.00  
21    122029.78  
22    122686.50  
23      5270.67  
24    127054.20  
25    315574.05  
26     13009.18  
27     14031.02  
28     80241.84  
29    392780.10  
30   1505888.07  
31     53252.50  
32    369155.00  
33   1367272.50  
34    404010.78  
35    160609.54  
36      9119.44  
37    272672.40  
38    846885.00  
39    503358.75  
40     75555.90  
41   1257775.58  
42    187545.03  
43     10795.23  
44    435499.20  
45     85223.58  
46   1541705.29  
47      6841.38  
48    575916.48  
49    159832.50  
50    166635.36  
51     23150.46  
52    359941.17  
53    436446.25  
54     18405.17  
55    255718.08  
56    727423.20  
57    495007.89  
58     46735.86  
59   1254472.05  
60     60418.38  
61    455335.00  
62    696647.50  
63    449159.04  
64    296448.35  
65    778415.99  
66    216919.36  
67    403773.12  
68   1046233.75  
69    539196.48  
70    632512.50  
71      1621.93  
72     89904.06  
73    766835.04  
74   1719922.04  
75   1152486.42  
76    146875.14  
77    235601.16  
78    825738.04  
79   1678540.98  
80    747939.49  
81    579000.96  
82   1128242.43  
83    225246.90  
84    407630.41  
85    160935.32  
86    138262.14  
87    532885.74  
88      1258.02  
89     72975.60  
90    119685.00  
91    147031.74  
92    255151.25  
93   1375311.70  
94    127722.96  
95     65214.72  
96     15103.47  
97     93748.05  
98    144521.02  
99    889472.91
```

you can see it is showing two columns only.

Can someone please help me to find out how can I see all the columns ? I mean all the columns together without linebreak(with scrolling)

I searched in internet but i found only to enable vertical scrolling. Can't it get horizontal scrolling ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add tag for the language. Looks like Python? Also, that code you show probably shouldn't be printing anything? Or does the `ge.read_csv` produce that output, in addition to presumably returning the csv contents in some data structure?

Comment: Oh ! I apologize. I forget to mention the language. I checked so many times if I am missing something but... anyways, I updated the question mentioned the language.
I added the line which produces the output. Thanks for not reducing more than 1 point.

Comment: Have you read the doxs of the classes? It'f be really strange if there are no means of output formatring.

Comment: Have you tried anything else, like putting the output to a string first, then printing that, or writing outout to a file and opening  it with text editor?

Comment: I am trying to open a csv file which is working fine and showing the records also. But not in a same line. It is showing with line breaks

Answer (score 0):

i have been too searching the answer for a very long time lol
but actually
instead of writing "print(my_df)" in jupyter notebbok
simply write "my_df" (that is the variable name where u have saved the csv file) , then hit "run" command

Comment: You can probably also use `display(my_df)` if you don't want it on the last of a cell or as the only line of a cell. This uses the rich representation in Jupyter, if that type of object has one and the name makes me think it may like a dataframe perhaps. `print()` is for standard text and for use in text-based console or command line-triggered output. One thing is that I think you should change to say "(that is the variable name where u have saved the csv file data)". It seems to have same the data from the file and not the file.

Comment: Confirmed now, `display(my_df)` works to get a rich HTML table of the dataframe to display in Jupyter. That way you can have other expressions or `print()` statements in the same code cell below where you invoke displaying `my_df`. And it is indeed a dataframe oabject. The type for `my_df` is `great_expectations.dataset.pandas_dataset.PandasDataset` and so it is Pandas dataframe underneath the extras the package `great_expectations` adds on top behind-the-scenes.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35753086)